# Send Outlook 2010 email using PHP

Tags: php, email, outlook

I'm looking to use the default Windows 7 Outlook 2010 mail account to send an email.

I've tried:

```
oApp  = new COM("Outlook.Application") or die('error');
$oMsg  = $oApp ->CreateItem($oApp->OlItemType->olMailItem);
$oMsg ->Recipients->Add("xxx@xxx.com");
$oMsg ->Subject="aaaa";
$oMsg ->Body="body";
$oMsg ->Save();
$oMsg ->Send();
```

But I get the error:

```
Outlook loaded, version 14.0.0.7109
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Unable to lookup  
`OlItemType': Unknown name. ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet_IT_Request_Form
\comunread.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet_IT_Request_Form
\comunread.php(5): unknown() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs
\Intranet_IT_Request_Form\comunread.php on line 5
```

My research tells me I need cdo.dll, which contains all the email functions, but I can only install this with Outlook 2007; not practical at all.

Does anyone know how to send an Outlook 2010 email using PHP? (I'm using XAMPP).

Many many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
if (!defined("olMailItem")) {define("olMailItem",0);}
$oApp  = new COM("Outlook.Application") or die('error');
$oMsg = $oApp->CreateItem(olMailItem);
$oMsg->Recipients->Add("xxx@xxx.org");
$oMsg->Subject=$subject;
$oMsg->Body=$message;
$oMsg->Save();
$oMsg->Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the next code works just out of the box:

```
<?php
```

$subject="This is a test message";

$message="This is a Body Section now.....! :)";

$to="someaddress@somedomain.com";

// starting outlook

**com_load_typelib("outlook.application");**

if (!defined("olMailItem")) {define("olMailItem",0);}

$outlook_Obj = new COM("outlook.application") or die("Unable to start Outlook");

//just to check you are connected.

echo "Loaded MS Outlook, version {$outlook_Obj->Version}\n";

$oMsg = $outlook_Obj->CreateItem(olMailItem);

$oMsg->Recipients->Add($to);

$oMsg->Subject=$subject;

$oMsg->Body=$message;

$oMsg->Save();

$oMsg->Send();

?>

Please, ensure that you have added

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

at the end of php.ini (In my case I have PHP 5.3)